# How to ask a good question on Tridion Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I've had a few customers hesitate at asking Tridion questions because they're not sure *how* to ask or might be new to asking online.

This isn't quite a new problem and we already have some good tips:

- Tridion Stack Exchange [help](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help) explains [how to ask a good question](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
- The old Tridion forum cited Eric Steven Raymond's classic "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)."

Is there anything else you would recommend, in the context of asking Tridion Stack Exchange questions? **What do you expect from a good Tridion question?** Remember to [be nice](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 2):

I think the biggest thing I see is someone will post a question, then the first few comments will be people asking for the same pieces of information:

- What version of Tridion are you using?
- Which hotfixes have you installed?
- Can you post any logs?
- What have you tried already (so we don't waste your time on suggestions that already haven't worked)?

Often times clues to the answer can be somewhere you're not initially expecting, so the more information you post with the initial question the quicker you'll start getting answers.